# Show all results for employees earning less than ALLEN in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to do this query but it doesn't work for me.

Show all results for employees earning less than ALLEN

This is the employees table:

```
 EmpNb, EName, -  Job,     Mgr,   HireDate,    Sal,       Comm,     DeptNb
 7499,  ALLEN,  SALESMAN,  7698,  1981-02-20,  1600.00 ,  300.00,   30
 7654,  MARTIN, SALESMAN,  7698,  1981-09-28,  1250.00,   1400.00,  30
 7934,  MILLER, CLERK,     7782,  1982-01-23,  1300.00,   NULL,     10
 7844,  TURNER, SALESMAN,  7698,  1981-09-08,  1500.00,   0.00,     30 
 7782,  CLARK,  MANAGER,   7839,  1981-06-09,  2450.00,   NULL,     10
 7698,  BLAKE,  MANAGER,   7839,  1981-05-01,  2850.00,   NULL,     30
```

I need help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A subquery should do the job:

```
select * from employees
where Sal < (select Sal from employees where EName = 'ALLEN')
```